# Isabelle: Switching between "structured" and "apply-style" proofs

Tags: isabelle, isar

There are two styles of proof in Isabelle: the old "apply" style, where a proof is just a chain of

```
apply (this method) 
apply (that method)
```

statements, and the new "structured" Isar style. Myself, I find both useful; "apply" style is more concise, and so is handy for uninteresting technical lemmas, while "structured" style is handy for the major theorems.

Sometimes I like to switch from one style to the other, mid-proof. Switching from "apply" style to "structured" style is easy: I just insert

```
proof -
```

in my apply-chain. My question is: how can I switch from "structured" style back to "apply" style?

To give a more concrete example: suppose I have five subgoals. I issue some "apply" instructions to despatch the first two subgoals. Then I launch into a structured proof to dispense with the third. I have two subgoals remaining: how do I return to "apply" style for these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can continue in "apply" style within a structured proof by using `apply_end` instead of `apply`, but this is rarely seen in practice and only during explorative work. In a polished proof, you would just pick the subgoals that merit an Isar proof and finish off all the remaining subgoals in one method call after the `qed`, as there is no need to deal with the subgoals in any specific order.

Alternatively, you can use `defer` before you start the structured proof with `proof` and continue immediately with the other subgoals in "apply" style, i.e., you defer the goals with structured proofs until the end.

And finally, you can of course re-state your goal in the structured proof with `fix`/`assume`/`show` and continue with "apply" style there. But you have to do this for each remaining subgoal separately, so this might be a bit tedious. The default case names `goal1`, `goal2`, etc. help a bit with typing, but such proofs are typically hard to maintain (especially as `apply_end` changes the goal numbering for `goal<n>`).